Smalleness condition of sets
In Hovey's book (Model Categories) he define a small object, and then he proves that every set $A$ is $|A|$-small, but I didn't understand what he did. If $a\in A$, then $f(a)\in colim_{\beta<\lambda}X_{\beta}$, as $X$ is a $\lambda$-sequence then $colim_{\beta<\lambda}X_{\beta}\cong X_{\beta'}$ where $\beta'$ is a limit ordinal and $\beta'<\lambda$.
I didn't understand how to for all $a\in A$ there is an ordinal $\beta_a$ such that $f(a)\in X_{\beta_a}$ and why he used $|A|$??




Every element of the colimit is in the image of some $X_\beta$. $|A|$-filteredness ensures that there is some $X_\beta$ whose image contains all of $f(A)$.

I don't think I understood correctly. Are the legs of the cones $X_\beta\rightarrow colim\ X_\beta$ surjective? I do not remember this. Oh in Set the legs of the cone are projections because the colimit is a quotient in the coproduct, is that it?
